# Joins with more than 2 or 3 tables, with Where clause using Lambda Expressions. Then sending the object to the View

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have created the query successfully for getting data from 6 tables via lambda expressions as well as other ways. (Sorry don't know what to call other methods I applied). Anyway, now the problem is, I don't know how to send this object to the View. In general I used to send the object of the model or ViewModel. Please help!

Thank you so much in advance!

I have tried creating ViewModel and included all objects included in the query but I am just unable to settle them down. May be its the wrong strategy or may I am just don't know how to do it.

```
var my = _context.Clients.Join(_context.Consultants, cli => cli.consultantID, con => con.ConsultantId,
            (cli, con) => new
            {
                aClient = cli,
                aConsultant = con
            }).Join(_context.ClientPhone.Where(ph => ph.PrimaryPhone), cli => cli.aClient.ClientCNIC, ph => ph.ClientCNIC, (cli, ph) => new
            {
                cli.aClient,
                cli.aConsultant,
                aPhone = ph
            }).Join(_context.clientemail.Where(e => e.PrimaryEmail), cli => cli.aClient.ClientCNIC, e => e.ClientCNIC, (cli, e) => new
            {
                cli.aClient,
                cli.aConsultant,
                cli.aPhone,
                aEmail = e
            }).Join(_context.ITRStatus, cli => cli.aClient.ClientCNIC, itr => itr.ClientCNIC, (cli, itr) => new
            {
                cli.aClient,
                cli.aConsultant,
                cli.aEmail,
                cli.aPhone,
                aItr = itr
            }).Join(_context.ClientStatus, cli => cli.aItr.ClientstatusId, ss => ss.clientstatusId, (cli, ss) => new
            {
                cli.aClient,
                cli.aConsultant,
                cli.aEmail,
                cli.aItr,
                cli.aPhone,
                aStatus = ss
            }).Select(s => new
            {
                s.aClient.clientName,
                s.aClient.ClientCNIC,
                s.aClient.ClientPassword,
                s.aConsultant.ConsultantName,
                s.aEmail.Email,
                s.aPhone.Phone,
                s.aStatus.StatusString
            }).ToList();

        return View(my);
```

What I expect the result to be, I somehow send the object to the View via Model and then Iterate the Model in the View using foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I tried several ways and found the solution to my own question!

Here is what I did.

simply created view model for the objects included in the query. Then as follows in the controller:

```
var viewModel = new List<ClientIndexViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in my)
        {
            viewModel.Add(new ClientIndexViewModel()
            {
                Client = item.aClient,
                Phone = item.aPhone,
                Consultant = item.aConsultant,
                Email = item.aEmail,
                ClientStatus = item.aStatus,
            });
        }
        return View(viewModel);
```

**View.cshtml**

```
 <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Client.clientName
            </td>
        </tr>
```

It is dynamic and do provide IntelliSense too. By the way, I have just posted the part of code that was enough to understand, pardon for any deficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like @model dynamic in your view.
That way you can pass directly your variable 'my' to it.

BTW, you will lose IntelliSense over your model

Comment: well, I know about `@model`. However, what do I write ahead of it? e.g. `@model List<projectfolder.viewmodels.sampleclass>`.

Comment: What about @model List<dynamic> ?

Comment: Its not working bro. Let me tell you, how I tried. I sent object "my" to the View. Then in View, @model List<dynamic> as you said. Then, created a foreach block, `foreach(var item in Model)` but when I do item. , it does not list anything from the "my" object.

Comment: Yes that's the thing. you won't get a list of the properties if you use dynamic. You can try this to see your object structure @ObjectInfo.Print(item) or just do the for and print some static value just to confirm that you are receiving the list in your view. After confirm this you should be able to access the properties of your object even if you don't see those listed. That's the IntelliSense I was telling about

Comment: Okay, I did as you said but foreach block did not iterate the objects. Because Model is Empty. I have other static data in the html view so it should have shown something if foreach loop Iterated the list a bit.

Comment: then I think that is possible that your query is not returning any result.

To create your object and not to use dynamics you can try to print your model in your view like this `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` that way you will have printed the object structure of your result, then you can use an option in visual studio Menu>Edit>Paste Special>Paste JSON as Classes, doing this you could generate your actual ModelView.
to do this you should first fix your query.
if you debug and see the `my` variable, before pass it to the view does it has records?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196423/discussion-between-imran-faruqi-and-user2055637).